# How to play a sound file with irrKlang, to which the path was inputted by the user

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, getline, irrklang

I am trying to make a music player in C++ with irrKlang. I want to make it so that you can enter the sound file's path with `getline(cin, filename)` and the engine plays that sound file for you. The problem is, `getline()` returns type `string` whereas irrKlang requires its own type `ISoundSource*`. I can't use `cin` either, as any space in the file path will just cut off everything after the character before it.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <irrKlang.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace irrklang;

int main()
{
    ISoundEngine* engine = createIrrKlangDevice();
    cout << "Enter path to sound: ";
    string filename;
    getline(cin, filename) //returns string
/*
    ISoundSource* ikfilename;
    getline(cinm ikfilename) //E0304 no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
*/
    engine->Play2D(filename); //E0304 no instance of overloaded function "irrklang::ISoundEngine::play2D" matches the argument list


}
```

I tried looking everywhere. There is no thread asking the same question as I am. I could not find any way to convert `string` into `ISoundSource*`. I have read the entire documentation and there is no mention of using a `string` variable as input anywhere. I'd need to embed the file path in the code itself for it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did not downvote however from years of experience on this site I expect you got downvoted because your question did not show that you made an effort to read the documentation and try to solve the problem yourself. One overload of the [Play2D function](https://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/docu/classirrklang_1_1_i_sound_engine.html#a25f612fe6479d3b22dc5bab2a2eaa927) takes a const char* filename which you can easily get from the [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) if you have basic c++ experience.

Comment: I am quite new to C++. I came from C# and am trying to recreate my program in C++. Sorry

Comment: Try: `engine->Play2D(filename.c_str());`

Comment: @drescherjm I have actually just found that. I had to debug some other lines before being able to test it though. Please write this as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I could not find any way to convert string into ISoundSource*.*** 
You don't need to convert a `std::string` into an `ISoundSource`. Instead there is an overload of [Play2D](https://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/docu/classirrklang_1_1_i_sound_engine.html#a25f612fe6479d3b22dc5bab2a2eaa927) that takes a const char*:

```
virtual ISound* irrklang::ISoundEngine::play2D  (   const char *    soundFileName,
bool    playLooped = false,
bool    startPaused = false,
bool    track = false,
E_STREAM_MODE   streamMode = ESM_AUTO_DETECT,
bool    enableSoundEffects = false   
)
```

So to use this use the [string::c_str() function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get a `const char*` from the `std::string` and so your call becomes:

```
engine->Play2D(filename.c_str());
```